# How to use ObjectAnimator for move view object in circular path using path.addCircle?

Tags: android

I'm try to move a view Object in circular path using android *android.animation.ObjectAnimator*

I tried with [this](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/reposition-view#CurvedMotion) and I got an error saying **The Path must start at (0,0) and end at (1,1)**

This is my OnClick() method of particular view object

```
public void onPathAnimation(View view){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(view.getX(), view.getY()+100);
        path.addCircle(view.getX(), view.getY(), 100, Path.Direction.CW);
        PathInterpolator pathInterpolator = new PathInterpolator(path);

        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationX", 100f);
        animator.setInterpolator(pathInterpolator);
        //  animator.setDuration(2000);
        animator.start();
    }
}
```

This is the exception I'm getting

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5265)
                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21534)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5737)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5265) 
                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21534) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5737) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Path must start at (0,0) and end at (1,1)
                                                                         at android.view.animation.PathInterpolator.initPath(PathInterpolator.java:164)
                                                                         at android.view.animation.PathInterpolator.<init>(PathInterpolator.java:61)
                                                                         at com.kalana.materialtest.MainActivity.onPathAnimation(MainActivity.java:179)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5265) 
                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21534) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5737) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Appreciating any advice.

Comment: use `ObjectAnimator#ofFloat(Object target, String xPropertyName, String yPropertyName, Path path)` or `ObjectAnimator#ofFloat(T target, Property<T, Float> xProperty, Property<T, Float> yProperty, Path path)` method

Comment: @pskink Thank you very much!

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 Path path = new Path();
 path.arcTo(50f, 800f, 1000f, 1000f, -180f, 145f, true);
 ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.X, View.Y, path);
 animation.setDuration(2000);  //animation duration
 animation.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the `addOval` method. I don't need to define any angles.

```
val path: Path = Path()
val ovalRect = RectF(
    left,
    top,
    right,
    bottom)

path.addOval(
    ovalRect,
    Path.Direction.CCW)

oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
    view,
    View.X,
    View.Y,
    path)
oa?.duration = MOVING_CAMERA_PREVIEW_TIME
oa?.repeatMode = ObjectAnimator.RESTART
oa?.repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE
oa?.start()
```